# Javascript transform array of object structure

Tags: javascript, object, array-map

I am trying to transform an array of objects structure from looking like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "varchar",
        type: "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "varchar",
        type: "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Into this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entitiesName: "varchar",
    entitiesType: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entitiesName: "varchar",
    entitiesType: "string"
  }
]
```

So more or less I want to take two values from `entities` and make them into key/values in the root object instead.

I have tried using `Object.entries(data).map()` but I am stuck

Comment: Indentation helps

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: There are so may questions about this on the site about doing this. Can you please try more things, do some research? Also, be clear on the logic to be used to get from one to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a destruction for collecting all wanted properties and build a new object.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, val: "bool", name: "somename", entities: [{ id: 1, name: "varchar", type: "string" }] }, { id: 2, val: "bool", name: "somename", entities: [{ id: 1, name: "varchar", type: "string" }] }],
    result = array.map(
        ({ id, val, name, entities: [{ name: entitiesName, type: entitiesType }] }) =>
        ({ id, val, name, entitiesName, entitiesType })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map()`

1. Create two new key value pairs `entitiesName` and `entitiesType`
2. Delete the `entities` key

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "varchar",
      type: "string"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "varchar",
      type: "string"
    }]
  }
];

data = data.map(
  (el) => {
      el.entitiesName = el.entities[0].name;
      el.entitiesType = el.entities[0].type;
      delete el.entities;
      return el;
  }
);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You're modifying the source array, so you don't need to return a "new" array.

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid modification on source array.**

```js
var data = [  {    id: 1,    val: "bool",    name: "somename",    entities: [      {        id: 1,        name: "varchar",        type: "string"      }    ]  },  {    id: 2,    val: "bool",    name: "somename",    entities: [      {        id: 1,        name: "varchar",        type: "string"      }    ]  }];

var result = data.map((o) => {
  var obj = {...o, 'entitiesName': o.entities[0].name, 'entitiesType': o.entities[0].type };
  delete obj.entities;
  
  return obj;
});

console.log(data);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using Array.map function of array  and spread operator

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "varchar1",
      type: "string"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: "bool",
    name: "somename",
    entities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "varchar2",
      type: "string"
    }]
  }
];
var result = data.map(
  (el) => {
      const { entities, ...noentities } = el;
      return {...noentities, entitiesName :el.entities[0].name ,entitiesType:el.entities[0].type}
  }
);
console.log(result)
```